# Spring boot show all autoConfiguration

Tags: spring-boot

I tried adding `--debug` flag to my Application. Am running my Application via IntelliJ IDEA.

Also tried adding -DDebug jvm param. That didnt work either.
I am wanting to list all autoconfiguration in my SpringBootApplication.
I am using Jersey, so actuator end point via spring MVC is not an option.

Any other means to know AutoConfiguration ?

Comment: Ok, I had a logback.xml that caused the debugs not to be printed. Removing it fixed it. However I still like to know what other  options when I do not want to have spring-boot-starter-mvc dependency and want to stick to jersey jax-rs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to use `--debug` and you don't want to use Spring MVC, then you remaining option is to use JMX. The `getData` operation on the `org.springframework.boot:type=Endpoint,name=autoConfigurationReportEndpoint` MBean will return a JSON version of the auto-configuration report.